# Liferay: Error opening portlet.xml from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide

I'm working with Eclipse Helios nd using Liferay Portal version 6.

I have already installed the Liferay IDE plugins and I installed the required software for working on this platform.

But I am still having an error when I try to open a  portlet.xml file from Eclipse:

```
    Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".
```

(Error log)

```
    An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
    org/eclipse/sapphire/modeling/ModelElementType
```

(Error view)

Does anyone knows how I can solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Your installed version of [Sapphire](http://eclipse.org/sapphire/) is not compatible with [Liferay IDE](http://www.liferay.com/community/liferay-projects/liferay-ide).  To fix the problem here are the steps:

1. Uninstall Liferay IDE feature
2. Uninstall all Sapphire features
3. Reinstall Liferay IDE from Helios updatesite: http://releases.liferay.com/tools/ide/eclipse/helios/stable doing this will install a compatible version of Sapphire automatically.
4. Try to reopen portlet.xml

**Note**: to uninstall a feature:

1. go to Help > About > Installation > Installed Software Tab
2. Select feature you want to uninstall
3. Click Uninstall
4. Restart